# How to make auto logout page in mvc after a some time

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Title- asp.net-mvc5 Auto logout How to make form auto logout after sometime in asp.net-mvc5 and redirect automatically to login page

Comment: you have to create a session to store the value of user-id and you need to write code to execute after a session expires.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a session variable on the `Login` method.
The session will be created by `Session["Userid"]=Userid;`. Then you need to create custom attribute to check session timeout.
Steps you need to follow are:

- Create a session variable in login() (Post method)
- Create a class file in your MVC project.
- Copy and paste below code in that file.

  public class SessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {

  ```
      Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

      HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;            
      var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
      string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
      string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");

      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] == null)
      {
          filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=" + currentController + "/" + currentAction);
          return;
      }
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
  ```

  }
- add [SessionTimeOut] attribute on each controller.

  [SessionTimeOut]

  public class ControllerName : Controller
  {

Comment: **Yes It Worked**

Answer (score 0):

You should add Statup.cs file.
1. Add Statup Class your project from new item lists.
2. Add following line in ConfigureService.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = 
                     false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            // we do this because we trust the network
            options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            options.KnownProxies.Clear();
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(x =>
                {
                    x.Cookie.Name = "WriteSomeThings";
                    x.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                    x.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                    x.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    x.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                    x.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);//For Auto Logout 
                    x.LoginPath = "/User/LogOn";
                    x.LogoutPath = "/User/LogOff";
                    x.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";

                });

    }
```

x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8) => This line allow us to logout automatically after 8 hours.

Answer (score -1):

If you need full user management check this video

https://youtu.be/912q3TEF25U

Software development template with role-based user management using ASP.NET MVC 5. Try it for free